# 2 guest VMs on the same host, remoting (via VNC/NoMachine) to each other

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, kvm, virt-manager

I have a very simple setup. Host is virt-manager running QEmu-KVM guests:

```
Host:     Ubuntu 20.04 (basic install)  
2 Guests: Ubuntu Mate 20.04 (basic install)
```

I have installed NoMachine (or VNC) on the 2 Guests.

**The issue:**  When I try to connect via NoMachine (or VNC) from Guest1 to Guest2, they cannot see each other.

I think I need to do some kind of port-forwarding on the Host. Can someone point me in the right direction?

They have the following network configurations:

---

Guest1 has virtual network configured via `virt-manager`:

```
          Name:    default
          Device:  virbr0
          IPv4 configuration:
          Network:    192.168.122.0/24
          DHCP range: 192.168.122.2 - 192.168.122.254
          Forwarding: NAT
```

Guest2 has virtual network configured via `virt-manager`:

```
          Name:    network
          Device:  virbr1
          IPv4 configuration:
          Network:    192.168.100.0/24
          DHCP range: 192.168.100.128 - 192.168.100.254
          Forwarding: NAT
```

Guest 1 is running its nxserver on 192.168.100.145

Guest 2 is running its nxserver on 192.168.122.146

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subnetting is wrong. Should be 192.168.122.0/16 on Guest 1 and 192.168.100.0/16 on Guest 2. Your entire network will need to be /16 in order for all devices to communicate.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much. I just had to put a subnet mask of 16 and put both guests on the *same* virtual-network.  Thanks again!!